# Render method not working by using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have trying to test the basic example provided in react-testing-library documentation. 
I exactly copied and pasted this code [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#basic-example)

It's failing no matter what.

Here the failing test result:

```
shows the children when the checkbox is checked

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

      34 | test('shows the children when the checkbox is checked', () => {
      35 |   const testMessage = 'Test Message'
    > 36 |   const {queryByText, getByLabelText, getByText} = render(
         |                                                    ^
      37 |     <HiddenMessage>{testMessage}</HiddenMessage>,
      38 |   )
      39 | 

      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:983:55)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1418:12)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:82:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Authentication/SignUp/index.test.js:36:52)

  ● shows the children when the checkbox is checked

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:983:55)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1418:12)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:57:20
      at asyncAct (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:38:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/index.js:28:35)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.318s, estimated 3s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code for `HiddenMessage` component.

Comment: I've added the link above. The code is exactly the same as the one used in the react-testing-library example. Just in case, here the link again: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#basic-example

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you have the latest versions of React, React DOM and testing library installed.

Comment: Yep, you were right Clarity. I've updated the version of react to the latest 16.9 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this as well from my research it looks like the `undefined` which `current` is being called on is `IsSomeRendererActing` inside of https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/test-utils/ReactTestUtilsAct.js#L79

It looks like a global var shared between react packages. The best advise I can give is to check that react dom react and react test utils and any other react packages all are at the same version

Answer (score -1):

This error is probably coming from inside the `HiddenMessage` component, rather than anything wrong in your test code. It looks like you’re trying to access `current` On something that doesn’t exist (maybe a `ref`?)

The test code looks right, you should track down where you’re trying to access `current` in `HiddenMessage`.